# Unable to get response that I sends using GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response on request made by client

Tags: php, request, response, guzzle

I am sending a request from the client using GuzzleHttp\Client to a page on another port that is serving as a server like

```
use SL\Controllers\LoginController;
use SL\FileHelper;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

require_once dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "config/config.php";

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('get','http://myip:75/src/LoginVerification.php?username=asd&password=asd');
```

The request is served on the page

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../config.php');

use Moodle\Manager\UserManager;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;

$userManager = new UserManager();
$user;


$username = $_GET["username"];
$password = $_GET["password"];

$isLogin = $userManager->verifyLogin($username, $password, $user);
if($isLogin)
    $body = "yahoo";
else
    $body = "oooops";

$status = 201;
$headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];
$protocol = '1.1';
$response = new Response($status, $headers, $body, $protocol);
return $response;
```

please ignore the password passing in GET as my main focus here is to send requests and get responses.

After the request is served on the server and response that I made is as below

```
phrases:array(58)
reasonPhrase:"Created"
statusCode:201
headers:array(1)
headerNames:array(1)
protocol:"1.1.1"
stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream
stream:resource id='10' type='stream'
size:null
seekable:true
readable:true
writable:true
uri:"php://temp"
```

But what is received is this

```
headerNames:array(9)
headers:array(9)
statusCode:200
reasonPhrase:"OK"
phrases:array(58)
protocol:"1.1"
headerNames:array(9)
headers:array(9)
phrases:array(58)
reasonPhrase:"OK"
statusCode:200
stream:resource id='4' type='stream'
size:null
seekable:true
readable:true
writable:true
uri:"php://temp"
```

It is not the same response that I had created.

Comment: What's the difference between the two that you are struggling with? What have you tried to check **why** there are differences?

Comment: Nico, the First that I have mentioned is a response created by me and it includes that in the stream when i get it right after setting in body [$response->getBody()->getcontents()] to verify that data is saved in response. but the second response is independent to what I do on the server side, if I don't create a response on server even then same reponse will be returned

Comment: `return $response` does not look like you are really **sending** the response

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332737/using-guzzlehttp-psr7-response-correctly help?

Comment: I had tried this as well but in this case, the user only sending status.. but I want to send the data in the body as well

Comment: And how do you properly send the response then? Using an object of a package that is meant to be used client-side does not work the same way as sending all the headers and properly handling the body

Comment: Nico, actually m not sing Laravel so I think sending a response of type GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response might not work, so I did an alternative thing, you can see it in my answer section.

Comment: Laravel does not know anything about that response object. The linked answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332737/using-guzzlehttp-psr7-response-correctly provides a good starting point for generating a **proper** HTTP response from that response object. Have you tried to use it?

Answer (score 0):

As I m not using Laravel so this issue of not getting the response that I want can be solved by making a simple stdClass object and echo this object by doing json_encode and then you can get the data in the response body.

```
$response = new stdClass();
$isLogin = $userManager->verifyLogin($username, $password, $user);
    if($isLogin)
        $response->body = "yahoo";
    else
        $response->body = "oooops";
    
    $response->status = 201;
    $response->headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];
    $response->protocol = '1.1';
    echo json_encode($response);
```

To get it on the client-side you just have to do this

```
$data = $response->getBody()->gtContents();
```